# Record set by URL parameter not being deleted from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a gallery page where users can delete photos they have uploaded.

The images can be deleted by following a link with the image id being passed as a variable, for example;

```
http://domain.com/delete-photo.php?imgid=3
```

But it isn't working, I can't seem to get the row to delete despite trying  a few different approaches. a search of the internet hasn't turnedup anything that worked either.

I either get an error or am redirected (as I should be) to the edit-gallery page.

My PHP code for delete-photo.php is;

```
<?php 
    require("includes/common.php");

    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    {  
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    } 

$imgid = $_GET['imgid'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM photos WHERE id='$imgid'";

header("location: edit-gallery.php");

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you're defining a variable `$sql` as a string, which contains the query you wish to run, but I don't see any code that then executes that query against the database. Is the code block in your question the complete code? If so, you'll need execute the query, preferably using a prepared statement and PDO to escape the image ID to prevent against SQL injection.

Comment: Also, not your problem here but DO NOT use get to delete data!  Use post.

Comment: Thanks... I have fixed the issue now. I needed to execute it - oops!

Comment: @AbraCadaver how do I switch it it out for POST

Comment: You build a form and post it.  Your link that you have can go to a confirmation form if you like, or just use a form instead of the link.  Make sure method="post".

Comment: @AbraCadaver Cool, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you forget to execute the query. you could use php PDO object.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure I included it, thought I missed it from the paste above but no I wasn't executing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by executing the query, I was forgetting to do that.

```
<?php 
    require("includes/common.php");

    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    {  
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    } 

$imgid = $_GET['imgid'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM photos WHERE id='$imgid'";

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( "$imgid" => $imgid ) );

header("location: edit-gallery.php");

?>
```